# Will a laptop run if the power source outputs lower current?

Tags: laptop, power

I need to work at a location where the power points output only ~2A (it is all solar).

The power brick with my laptop says it takes 2.35A input. Will this be fine?

What if I add an external monitor that takes 1A input?

Comment: https://thephoenixsun.com/solar-panels-for-computers/

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-run-a-computer-on-solar-power

Comment: The power brick is designed to work with a [voltage source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source), not with a [current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source). Mains electricity is a voltage source, the power brick expects a voltage source (being itself a voltage source for the laptop). The brick will draw as much current as it needs to satisfy the momentary demand for power from the laptop (plus losses). 2.35A is the max it is designed for. If the demand for current exceeds ~2A then the voltage will drop and things will "die" due to insufficient power. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) My point is it's the demand for power what matters, and it's not constant. If your setup keeps drawing low power then it may work. Run a demanding calculation, let the CPU and GPU work hard – and it may "die".

Comment: It may be wise to consider if using something less powerhungry than a laptop (for example a Raspberry Pi) would suffice.

Comment: To add to @KamilMaciorowski's answer, assuming you're not maxing out the CPU and GPU, it'll probably slightly charge or discharge the battery, depending on your current taxing of the laptop. So you might just be able to get a good number of hours of work out of it.

Comment: Assuming your laptop battery is fully charged, then *the laptop* will certainly work, at least for the battery's normal runtime, whether plugged into the 2 A source *or not*. However, at some point, the charging system of the laptop **might** demand more than 2 A, in which case, *eventually*, the power source overload *might* trip, or it *might* endure a short transient of slightly more than 2 A. Adding the extra 1 A of an external monitor makes overload shutdown *much* more likely.

Answer (score 2):

It will be fine sometimes.

So you don't have enough amps.
Your monitor will grab 1 amp leaving you with 1 amp.

Thus even if nothing bad happens (fire or etc) you will not be able to charge your laptop while its ON or it will take 5x-10x longer.

If you leave your laptop and monitor off you will be able to charge the battery inside the laptop at a pretty much normal rate, but maybe 10% longer.

When everything is turned on the laptop will consume as much as it need from the battery, but unless the draw is less than 1A then it will slowly deplete your battery.

Under certain loads like web browsing you might have barely enough.

If you peg the CPU at 100%, its going to drain your battery.